# Successfully uninstalled Google Cloud platform but I still get automatic updates. How to stop this?

Tags: update-manager, google

[PPA Active list Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFRtM.png)
[Image link of Software updater asking to update google cloud platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i95Xp.png)

I have followed the official [Cloud SDK Documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk) and uninstalled Google Cloud platform but I get this periodic update notification. How to completely uninstall this.

Comment: Is there a PPA active (see "software sources") for this?

Comment: I will update the question with the PPA active list. Kindly tell me which one to remove.